# reapply without recommendation from current advisor

Tags: phd, application, recommendation-letter, quitting

I'm a new PhD student in a middle-ranked university. I decided to accept my professor's offer because his publication matches my interests and has a reputable reputation from my research(like asking some PhD students who know him).

I figured out I was wrong after I worked for him. Last year, 4 students quit our lab(I didn't know that). All PhD students in the group don't like him. He doesn't respect the students. He told his peer that student A was bad and A's paper ended up in a no-name conference when introducing A to his peer or saying bad words to students when talking with other lab members. They no longer hand on projects but they like to command students in some field that they have little knowledge of. Personally. I wish an advisor could do research together with students or let students explore the fields and give some guidance. I'll also respect my professor if he really wants me to do some topic but he should let me follow some related projects to learn before giving me something that I have zero knowledge. However, my professor satisfies none of them. There are many other reasons but let's get straight to the point.

I recently decided to quit and reapply. But I don't think my professor will write me a recommendation letter if I quit based on my knowledge of him. Is the lack of the current advisor's recommendation a huge disadvantage if I reapply? I'm also worried that he will say some bad words about me if he agrees.